# Draw the segments from the given points

Tags: software-rec, graphics

I have a list of multiple points (>= 10000) in format

```
x y
```

For example

```
1 2
1.0001 2.003
...
```

Is there any Linux program to draw segment between the 1st and the 2nd, 2nd and the 3rd, n-th and the (n+1)-st segment, preferably as a vector graphic?

Comment: It's not specifically Linux, but take a look at `gnuplot`.

Answer (score 3):

As Joseph R. mentioned, there's the old classic `gnuplot`, plus a host of more modern offerings that can create all sorts of graphs in various formats, both vector-based and bitmapped. But such programs tend to be so versatile that it takes quite a while to learn how to use them properly, which can be a little daunting when all you want is to quickly plot a simple line graph.

I've been teaching myself about the SVG format recently, creating small SVG files by hand and also writing Python programs to draw various things using SVG, so when I saw your question I thought it was a perfect opportunity to do some more SVG programming practice. :)

Here's a crude Python program that makes a plain line graph from data in the format given in the question. The output is in SVG format, printed to stdout, so you'll need to use redirection to save it to a file. The input data is read from the file name specified on the command line, but if no file name is given the program reads its data from stdin, so the program can be used in a pipeline.

The input data can contain blank lines, or comment lines with `#` as the first non-blank character. The X and Y values on each line must be separated by at least one white space character (tabs are ok), other white space on a line is ignored, so spaces before the X value or after the Y value are ignored.

The program scans through all the X Y data to find the maximum and minimum values, which are used to calculate the SVG viewBox so that the plot is scaled and centered correctly.

**SVGgraph.py**

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Create a simple line graph as an SVG file

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.11.09
'''

import sys

def bounding_box(points):
    xtup, ytup = zip(*points)

    xlo = min(xtup)
    xhi = max(xtup)

    ylo = min(ytup)
    yhi = max(ytup)
    return xlo, ylo, xhi - xlo, yhi - ylo


def points_to_SVG(points, width, height):
    #Get graph bounds & adjust to allow for a margin
    xlo, ylo, xsize, ysize = bounding_box(points)
    margin = 0.02
    xmargin = xsize * margin
    ymargin = ysize * margin
    xlo -= xmargin
    xsize += 2 * xmargin
    ylo -= ymargin
    ysize += 2 * ymargin

    strokewidth = 2.0 * min(xsize, ysize) / float(max(width, height))

    head = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="%d" height="%d" viewBox="%f %f %f %f"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">\n\n''' % (width, height, xlo, ylo, xsize, ysize)

    body = '    <polyline points="\n' + '\n'.join(["%f, %f" % t for t in points]) + '\n"\n'

    tail = 'style="fill:none; stroke-width:%f; stroke:#006600;"/>\n</svg>' % strokewidth

    return head + body + tail


def main():
    iname = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None
    f = open(iname, 'rt') if iname else sys.stdin

    data = f.read().splitlines()
    if iname is not None:
        f.close()

    points = []
    for line in data:
        #Skip blank lines
        if not line: continue

        x, y = line.split()

        #Skip comments: lines which have '#' as the first non-blank char
        if x.startswith('#'): continue

        points.append((float(x), float(y)))

    width, height = 800, 600
    print points_to_SVG(points, width, height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's some sample output:

**graphtest.svg**

```svg
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="800" height="600" viewBox="-0.240855 -3.881333 12.524483 7.762666"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

    <polyline points="
0.000000, 0.000000
0.523599, 3.732051
1.047198, 2.598076
1.570796, -0.500000
2.094395, -0.866025
2.617994, 0.267949
3.141593, 0.000000
3.665191, -0.267949
4.188790, 0.866025
4.712389, 0.500000
5.235988, -2.598076
5.759587, -3.732051
6.283185, -0.000000
6.806784, 3.732051
7.330383, 2.598076
7.853982, -0.500000
8.377580, -0.866025
8.901179, 0.267949
9.424778, 0.000000
9.948377, -0.267949
10.471976, 0.866025
10.995574, 0.500000
11.519173, -2.598076
12.042772, -3.732051
"
style="fill:none; stroke-width:0.019407; stroke:#006600;"/>
</svg>
```

FWIW, here's the program I used to generate the test data for that SVG.

**SVGgraph-points.py**

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Create a list of points to test SVGgraph.py with

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.11.09
'''

import sys
from math import pi, sin

def f(x):
    return sin(x) + 2.0 * sin(x * 2.0) + 1.5 * sin(x * 3.0)

def make_points(n):
    points = n * [None]
    for i in xrange(n):
        x = 4.0 * pi * i / n
        y = f(x)
        points[i] = (x, y)
    return points


def main():
    n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 24
    points = make_points(n)
    print '\n'.join(["%f %f" % t for t in points])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Usage**

```
python SVGgraph-points.py 24 > testdata
python SVGgraph.py testdata > graphtest.svg
```

or

```
python SVGgraph-points.py | python SVGgraph.py > graphtest.svg
```

Give SVGgraph-points.py an argument of 200 or higher to create a smooth graph.

As I said above, this is just a crude script; I didn't feel like adding fancy command line handling. :)

You may wish to modify the `width` and `height` parameters, either in the Python script or in the SVG, but they aren't critical since SVG display programs generally allow you to control the scale while viewing images. And even if you edit those values in the SVG file the image will always be centered and scaled appropriately so that no parts get cut off.

You may also like to experiment with the `margin` scaling factor, currently set at 0.02, which determines the minimum margin around the graph. You can control the (nominal) thickness of the plotted line by adjusting the `strokewidth` multiplier, which is currently set at 2.0.

Have fun!

---

**Edit**

Here's a new version of the graphing script which uses a conventional coordinate system, rather than the inverted system that SVG (and many other computer drawing systems) uses. So now your graphs won't be upside down. :)

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Create a simple line graph as an SVG file

    Uses a conventional coordinate system,
    not the usual inverted SVG system.

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.11.11
'''

import sys

def bounding_box(points):
    xtup, ytup = zip(*points)

    xlo = min(xtup)
    xhi = max(xtup)

    ylo = min(ytup)
    yhi = max(ytup)
    return xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi


def points_to_SVG(points, width, height):
    #Get graph bounds & adjust to allow for a margin
    xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi = bounding_box(points)
    xsize = xhi - xlo
    ysize = yhi - ylo

    margin = 0.02
    xmargin = xsize * margin
    ymargin = ysize * margin
    xlo -= xmargin
    xsize += 2 * xmargin
    yhi += ymargin
    ysize += 2 * ymargin

    strokewidth = 2.0 * min(xsize, ysize) / float(max(width, height))

    head = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="%d" height="%d" viewBox="%f %f %f %f"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

    <polyline style="fill:none; stroke-width:%f; stroke:#006600;"
        transform="scale(1, -1)"
        points="\n''' % (width, height, xlo, -yhi, xsize, ysize, strokewidth)

    body = '\n'.join(["%f, %f" % t for t in points]) 

    tail = '\n"/>\n</svg>'

    return head + body + tail


def main():
    iname = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None
    f = open(iname, 'rt') if iname else sys.stdin

    data = f.read().splitlines()
    if iname is not None:
        f.close()

    points = []
    for line in data:
        #Skip blank lines
        if not line: continue

        x, y = line.split()

        #Skip comments: lines which have '#' as the first non-blank char
        if x.startswith('#'): continue

        points.append((float(x), float(y)))

    width, height = 800, 600
    print points_to_SVG(points, width, height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Graph plotted by this script is inverted. Compare with the same graph plotted by gnuplot or create some easy data such as `1 1; 1 -1; 0 0; -3 -2`. The semicolon indicates a newline in this comment

Comment: @marmistrz:Sorry about that! I forgot that SVG uses an inverted coordinate system. My excuse is that I'd been programming in PostScript over the last few days, which uses a proper coordinate system. :) But I'll put a repaired version in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a small script. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rvg/rvg'
require 'scanf'
include Magick

RVG::dpi = 72

rvg = RVG.new(2.5.in, 2.5.in).viewbox(0,0,300,300) do |canvas|
    canvas.styles(:stroke=>'black', :stroke_width=>4)
    oldx=oldy=nil
    ARGF.map{|line| line.scanf("%f %f")}.each do | x,y |
       canvas.line(oldx,oldy,x,y) if oldx
       oldx,oldy=x,y
    end
end

rvg.draw.write('output.png')
```

This opens a new canvas, draws the lines on it and writes the result to a file.